# Spectral decomposition of $TT^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

On $l_{2}$ let $T$ be given by $Te_{n}=\frac{e_{n+1}}{n+1}$ where $(e_{n})_{n\ge1}$ is the canonical orthonormal basis. Find the spectral decomposition of $TT^*$.

I find that $T^*(e_{n})=\frac{e_{n-1}}{n}$ for $n$ greater than 1 and $T^*(e_{1})=0$
I find that the $e_{n}$ are the orthonormal eigenvectors for $TT^*$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for $n\ge2$ and $0$ for $n=1$ so that the spectral decomposition is $TT^*x=\sum_{i=2}^{{\infty}}\frac{1}{n^2}\langle x,e_{n}\rangle e_{n}$.

Do you agree and if so, are there any which are a bit harder? Thanks

Comment: You have a typo: you have given the spectral decomposition of $T^{\star}T$, not $T$. The spectral decomposition of $TT^{\star}$ is not the same as that for $T^{\star}T$ because $TT^{\star}e_{1}=0$.

Comment: @T.A.E. No I said the decomposition of $TT^{*}$. But you agree?

Comment: Then you're over-using 'T' in your problem statement when you write $Tx=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}...$. (Also the sum index should be n) But you do have $T^{\star}T=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}...$ and $TT^{\star}$ is the same except that the sum should start at $n=2$.

Comment: I need to correct the last remark. I got the shifts wrong. $TT^{\star}x=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ and $T^{\star}Tx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$. I think that's correct.

Comment: sorry I made a few slips there @T.A.E. From here its also easy to find the decomposition of T

Comment: What do you mean by a (spectral) decomposition of $T$?

Comment: @T.A.E. T is compact so it has a spectral decomposition. We can write T as a series involving the eigenvectors of $|T|$.

Comment: What if $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$ for a compact operator $T$? What kind of spectral decomposition do you get?

Comment: @T.A.E. Yeah I guess in that case the decomposition reduces to zero by convention. Pretty pathological case though.